# How to build an "equilibrated histogram"?

Tags: r, histogram

I would like to create an "equilibrated histogram" with roughly the same number of data points in each bin. The second restriction I have is that I should have only 4 bins. Given the following list of numbers below, how can I achieve that?

-2.153, -1.732, -1.699, -1.559, -1.355, -1.306, -1.151, -1.129, -0.636, 0.4085, 0.5408, 0.5731, 0.5842, 0.6206, 0.8175, 0.8274, 0.8710, 1.3214, 1.5552, 2.2342

Thanks!

Comment: added R tag for appropriate syntax highlighting..

Comment: @Chase - I didn't realize the tag did that. Good to know!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To follow up on @mbq's suggestion, here's the code to do that with R:

```
require(Hmisc)

x <- c(-2.153, -1.732, -1.699, -1.559, -1.355
, -1.306, -1.151, -1.129, -0.636, 0.4085
, 0.5408, 0.5731, 0.5842, 0.6206, 0.8175
, 0.8274, 0.8710, 1.3214, 1.5552, 2.2342
)
eqBins <- cut2(x, g = 4)

#what are the bins and how many in each?
> as.data.frame(table(eqBins))
            eqBins Freq
 1 [-2.153,-1.306)    5
 2 [-1.306, 0.541)    5
 3 [ 0.541, 0.827)    5
 4 [ 0.827, 2.234]    5
```

Comment: (+1) Shouldn't it be `cut2(x, ...)`? Also, I don't think you need to assign a value to `m`: The only constraint in the question was about the No. groups.

Comment: @chl - doh! You are right on both accounts. I'm not sure why I thought it was necessary to pass arguments to both `g` and `m`. Code modified accordingly.

Comment: How can I get cuts from eqBins?

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for [quantiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile); in R there is a function `quantile` that will calculate them for you; `Hmisc` R package provides `cut2` function which explicitly calculates such "equilibrated bins".

Comment: (+1) Huh, `Hmisc`... a really great package!

Answer (score 1):

There's a histogram [here](http://gallery.r-enthusiasts.com/graph/Histogram_with_equal_counts_89), with R code that does approximately equal counts using the quantile function.

There's also the histogram function in the lattice package that comes with R. Compare:

```
library("lattice")
histogram(islands^(1/4))  # equal width
histogram(islands^(1/4),breaks=NULL,equal.widths=FALSE)  # approx. equal area
```